# How to use microphone on a computer (PC) with a 4-contact TRRS?

Tags: audio, microphone, headset

I have a Dell PC that has a single input for microphone and audio.

I connected a Mobile Phone Headset to it. Speakers work well but the microphone is not working.

What should I do?

(When I connect it to a PC, it asks which device did you plug-in:

- Line In
- Mic In
- Headset
- Headphone
- Skullcandy Headphone
- Skullcandy Headset
- Speaker out
- Dell Speaker out

Comment: What model is that dell pc?

Answer (score 0):

Now, it is working.
From Option, I selected "Headset".
(And made a small change in Recording devices setting).

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you expand your answer a little to clarify where Option is found and what change you made in the setting?

Comment: Hi, a reminder to post what your solution was

Comment: He simply went into its audio settings/control panel (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42910989/5994170)) and retasked the jack role. On the other hand, I guess here OP was talking about a laptop with a TRRS connector to begin with. On a normal [HDA](https://superuser.com/q/1142944/567466) desktop, AFAIK "headset" (or maybe it would be called headphone) would just make the audio output work, with no microphone (and viceversa when "Mic In" is selected).

Comment: Certain Dell devices have audio drivers that require you to choose the audio device  when you connect something to the analog audio connector. In their default state the drivers will popup a window allowing you to select the device, though you can tell the system not to ask and then it will always assume it will be a single decide type. This is still the case with current Dell devices.