# How to connect 3.5 mm 4-conductor jack headset to computer with 100% functionality?

Tags: audio, headphone-jack

I got Sony headset with 3.5 mm 4-conductor jack. It has microphone and a button on the wire and it works fine with mobile phones and tablets.

But how to use it with a desktop computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Its unlikely unless your desktop does. Mic and headset will work with a splitter, buttons *will not*

Primarily this is because your PC uses a different wiring/control scheme (HD Audio or AC/97) entirely seperate from what any phone uses. Your inputs are also likely to be *dual* trs (though many laptops do TRRS and a single input/output port), requiring a splitter, rather than TRRS of any flavour. Your buttons *will* not work

"100%" functionality is tricky - there's at least 3 (and probably 4 or more) ways the trrs connector can be wired - for example, apple have their own style, and there's at least two 'common' styles of wiring - OMTP and CTIA/AHJ.

To make things more confusing, while AHJ seems to be the 'common' android default and most PCs use it, I've never seen a PC that's 'aware' of the button, and there's two common button layouts - a universal single button, and a 3 button variation supported mainly by chinese OEMs.

So, in short, your PC needs to support it natively, and its somewhat unlikely that it does.  Your mic and headset should work fine with a combo jack or a splitter. Your button(s) likely will not.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need an adaptor, like [this TRRS to 2 TRS](http://www.showmecables.com/product/iPhone-Head-Set-Breakout-Cable-3-5mm-TRRS-Jack-to-Dual-3-5mm-Stereo-Plug-6-IN.aspx) and connect to your headphone and mic jack. Instructions will highlight which to plug in where.

You'll then need an [extension](http://www.showmecables.com/product/3-5mm-TRRS-Plug-to-3-5mm-TRRS-Jack-12-FT.aspx)